# .htaccess poiting a domain to another domain/directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns

I need to modify .htaccess file so that I can override my domain.
First I tell you that I don't know anything about .htaccess file.
And there is already a lot of stuff in that .htaccess file.

What I want is to redirect my

```
www.one-domain.com
```

to

```
www.second-domain.com/abc
```

I don't want anything else to change. Only one-domain.com start showing content of second-domain.com/abc

Between both sites for domain are of wordpress.

one-domain.com content is at `root/`
second-domain.com content is at `root/direcoty`

Below is content of my .htaccess file that it already has.

```
# -FrontPage-
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Just `www.onedomain.com` to `www.second-domain.com/abc` or `www.onedomain.com/foo` to `www.second-domain.com/abc/foo` also? This will be an external redirect and will change the URL in browser also, is that okay?

Comment: Just www.onedomain.com to www.second-domain.com/abc only. However I don't want external redirect but still that will be fine and will work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this code just below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?one-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.second-domain.com/abc [L,R=301]
```

Also note that this block is repeating multiple times:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**You need to have this block only once in your .htaccess**